# stackoverflowerror in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, stack-overflow

I'm new to kotlin and I have a problem with code: I don't know why exactly when I create an instance of a class it gives me a stackoverflow error

Here is the code :

```
class Spice(val spiceName: String,val spiciness: String = "mild") {

    init {
        println("[$spiceName - $spiciness] ")
    }

    val spiceList: List<Spice> = listOf(
            Spice("curry", "mild"),
            Spice("pepper", "medium"),
            Spice("cayenne", "spicy"),
            Spice("ginger", "mild"),
            Spice("red curry", "medium"),
            Spice("green curry", "mild"),
            Spice("hot pepper", "extremely spicy"))

    val heat: Int
        get() {
            return when (spiciness) {
                "mild" -> 1
                "medium" -> 3
                "spicy" -> 5
                "very spicy" -> 7
                "extremely spicy" -> 10
                else -> 0
            }
        }


    fun makeSalt() = Spice("Salt")

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because You're creating a new instance of your `Spice()` class whenever you call

```
val spiceList: List<Spice> = listOf(
  Spice("curry", "mild"),
  Spice("pepper", "medium"),
  Spice("cayenne", "spicy"),
  Spice("ginger", "mild"),
  Spice("red curry", "medium"),
  Spice("green curry", "mild"),
  Spice("hot pepper", "extremely spicy"))
```

What's happening is that at runtime the first line that will execute is the `init` block so you'll print.

```
[Whatever you passed in for your first param, "mild"]
```

then when you you're past the `init` you move on to evaluating

```
val spiceList = listOf(....)
```

in Kotlin, assignments are resolved at *runtime* meaning, even though you're not using `spiceList`, you're still creating it at that line, along with all the other `Spice()` objects inside it.

You'll notice that before you get the stackoverflow, you actually print

```
[Whatever you passed in for your first param, "mild"]
["curry", "mild"] x thousands of times
```

Because you're instantiating Spices within Spices, you'll always be stuck in that loop.

You could move your list to a companion object, which would be treated like a static is in Java, and that way it won't be resolved whenever you instantiate the Spice class

Answer (score 6):

It's because of `spiceList` field: every instance of `Spice` will try to initialize this field and hence create a list of `Spice`s, each of which will create a new list and so on.

You could move `spiceList` to a [companion object](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/objects-and-companion-objects.html#companion-objects) to make it tied to a class rather than to instances of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your mistake:

```
val spiceList: List<Spice> = listOf(
Spice("curry", "mild"),
Spice("pepper", "medium"),
Spice("cayenne", "spicy"),
Spice("ginger", "mild"),
Spice("red curry", "medium"),
Spice("green curry", "mild"),
Spice("hot pepper", "extremely spicy"))
```

you are creating list of spices in each instance, and each Spice item in the list is creating list of spices and so on, then you will face a burst!.
you could use a sealed class for this situation, or just use companion object to make it as a static list.